# Sending Data From One Page To The Other Page

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a serious problem.
I have two pages (such as `settingpage` and `MainPage`). In `settingpage`, I have a `switchbutton` with two value (`English` and `China`) 
I want when click on `switchbutton` don't navigate form `page1` to `page2` for sending data but I want change some data on `page2` such as format number and ... without navigate or change page.

How I can do it?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think its possible in windows phone 8. You can store the data in persistence and show them when you go to the other page. And another thing you can do is using master page, so that you can access the same data in both the scree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways with which you can achieve this.

1. Create a static variable on any of the pages and use it as `PageName.variableName` to access the variable or to set its value.
2. Use a singleton. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx